# why return empty list when calling list on zip twice

Tags: python, list

As below python code shows, why it prints empty list when call the second `list(ll)`?

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
ll = zip(l1,l2,l1,l2)
ll
<zip at 0x23d50b10f40>
list(ll)
[(1, 4, 1, 4), (2, 5, 2, 5), (3, 6, 3, 6)]
ll
<zip at 0x23d50b10f40>
list(ll)
[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `zip` is an Iterator object. When you call `list(ll)` for the first time, the values in the `zip` objects, get consumed. That is why when you call `list` again, there is nothing else to show.

`zip` is a function, that when applied on iterables, returns an iterator. Meaning, unless it is being iterated on, it does not calculate any value.

For example:

```
>>> z = zip([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5])
>>> z
<zip at 0x1e46824bec0>

>>> next(z)    # One value is computed, thus consumed, now if you call list:
(1, 3)

>>> list(z)    # There were only two left, and now even those two are consumed
[(2, 4), (3, 5)]

>>> list(z)    # Returns empty list because there is nothing to consume
[]
```